# Como habilitar recurso autocompletar para shell script?

Tags: linux, shell-script

Gostaria que as opções do meu shell script fossem apresentadas ou autocompletadas ao pressionar TAB, tal qual ocorre com comandos como aptitude ou yum.

Como habilitar recurso autocompletar para shell script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira mais fácil de fazer isso é incluir um script de shell em /etc/bash_completion.d/. A estrutura básica deste arquivo é uma função simples que executa a conclusão e, em seguida, a invocação de complete que é um compilador de bash. Em vez de entrar em detalhes sobre como usar complete, sugiro que você leia uma Introdução ao [Bash Completion](https://debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1). A Parte 1 cobre o básico e a Parte 2 entra em como você faria escrever um script de conclusão.